# "find" utility and multiple expressions with/without -a

Tags: shell, unix

Is there any difference between

```
find . ! -name name1 ! -name name2
```

and

```
find . ! -name name1 -a ! -name name2
```

In what cases should I use "-a"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `find` man page states, all primaries are implicitly "anded", unless you specifically say otherwise. So the two commands are indeed equivalent.

Relevant POSIX quote:

> expression  **[-a]**  expression
>
> ```
> Conjunction of primaries; the AND operator is implied by the
> juxtaposition of two primaries or made explicit by the optional -a
> operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first
> expression is false.
> ```

So you never need `-a` but it may be more readable for larger expressions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. -a ist short for -and, and when you dont give it, its the default (other possible non unary operators are "or" and ",").

Comment: Nitpick: none of `-and`, `-or` and `,` are standard (POSIX) options. These are all GNUisms. It is always a good idea to stick to POSIX if possible, especially when answering questions where the OP did not specify any particular OS. Read all about POSIX `find` here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html

Comment: Jens: Even on the other systems I used (AIX, HPUX, Solaris,...) we have installed the gnu versions of all the utils (grep, awk, find, ....) - I forget sometimes about it. You are absolutely right.